# Elasticsearch - filtering in scope of match

Tags: elasticsearch

in Elasticsearch I have five documents. They have name and colors:

- name: Car 1, colors: blue, green
- name: Car 2, colors: red, yellow
- name: Car 3, colors: brown, gold
- name: Bike 1, colors: blue, yellow
- name: Bike 2, colors: red, green

I want to **search** by the name and withing the scope on found results I want to **filter** it by color:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query":"Car"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "colors": "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this query returns me `Car 2` and `Bike 2` because of they colors. I understand why (filter is deciding to include them based on color), but have no idea how to write it that what will be included is based on the match and within those matched results I want to filter out those without a proper color.

Thanks

Comment: You `must` instead of `should` and it will work

Comment: Yes, it it working, thanks. But what if I would have to search for `car` in more fields, like `name` and `category` (OR)? Than I have to use `should`, right? So put sub-`bool` with `should`?

Comment: You can use [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) for that

Comment: Thanks! Got it working, `multi_match` with `filter`